# Leaving 1st column name blank in R when renaming columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Apologies if this question is redundant, although I did go through your questions extensively.

I am creating a new data frame from an old data frame using only selective columns from old data frame. I am using explicit row names in write.table. In the output, the column name of first original column is instead assigned to first column which is now the column contains explicit row names.

my code:

```
newfile1<-data.frame("chrs"=chrm1,"pos"=probes$Start,"S1"=probes$Value)
file.create("Tumor_LogR.txt")
write.table(newfile1, file="Tumor_LogR.txt", 
            row.names=snptags, col.names=TRUE, quote=FALSE)
```

output:

```
chrs    pos S1  
SNP1    1   683543  0.0698999986  
SNP2    1   744055  0.4013999999  
SNP3    1   744264  0.8565999866  
SNP4    1   788822  -0.6856999993  
SNP5    1   1038818 -0.1844000071
```

The "chrs" label is assigned to first column whereas it was originally assigned to the 2nd column.

How do I fix this??
Many thanks!!

Comment: You can find the answer in `help(write.table)`.

Comment: Thanks, I did! But I can't find it there.

Comment: Make the rownames a real column with a blank column name or assign the rownames to the data.frame and use `write.csv`.

Comment: I also tried adding column names explicitly like this
colnames(newfile1)[2] <- 'chrs'
colnames(newfile1)[3] <- 'pos'
colnames(newfile1)[4] <- 'S1'

Comment: Could you give an example of how the perfect output would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `col.names=NA` as described in the help file:

> By default there is no column name for a column of row names. If
>   col.names = NA and row.names = TRUE a blank column name is added,
>   which is the convention used for CSV files to be read by spreadsheets.

For example:

```
write.table(mtcars[1:3,1:3],col.names=NA)
"" "mpg" "cyl" "disp"
"Mazda RX4" 21 6 160
"Mazda RX4 Wag" 21 6 160
"Datsun 710" 22.8 4 108
```

Answer (score 0):

There no real reason to give the column new names.

```
newfile1<-data.frame(chrm1, probes$Start, probes$Value)
```

This gives you a dataframe that contain the columns with their old names.

Comment: Thanks! I need to give new names to the columns as I want to run another code on this file which only accepts these particular column names.